# jQuery No-Ui-Slider, how to lock multiple interconnected sliders to always sum 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-slider

I am using NoUiSlider in some pages which could have 3, 4 or 5 sliders (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

I need to set the sliders to have a total value which is constrained to 100, so that if I raise the value of a slider, the others should lower a little and vice-versa, but I really don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

jQuery code:

```
$(".slider.tied").each(function() {
    var context = $(this).addClass("noUiSlider");
    var input = context.prev(".amount"); // the input containing the actual slider value
    var val = input.val();
    var min = input.data("min");
    var max = input.data("max");

    context.noUiSlider({
        range: [min, max],
        start: val,
        step: 1,
        handles: 1,
        slide: function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            input.val(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've even tried with jQuery UI sliders, as someone tried to do something similar to what I need, but still no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/vuQz5/
Here I'm facing 2 problems: 1) It is possible to have a sum which is less than 100%, and 2) sometimes the sum is greater. I just need to have a total of 100%, always...

Comment: Can you explain more "the others should lower a little and vice-versa"  i think the problem is not UI it is more of "Synchronization" logic ? if you hae 10 slider and if one of them is lowered - how it should impact others ? some ratio must be defined .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
var init = true;
var elements = $(".multislider").children(".slider.tied").length;
var MAX = 100;
var initValue = (MAX / elements) >> 0;
var InitMod = MAX % elements;

$(".slider.tied").each(function() {
    var slidersTied = $(".slider.tied");
    var context = $(this);

    var input = context.prev(".amount");
    var val = input.data('answer');
    var min = input.data('min');
    var max = input.data('max');
    var range = 1;
    var proceed = false;

    $(this).empty().slider({
        value: val,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        range: range,
        animate: "slow",
        create: function(event, ui){

            if (InitMod > 0) {
                $(this).slider('value', initValue + 1);
                $(this).prev('.amount').val(initValue + 1);
                InitMod = InitMod - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).slider('value', initValue);
                $(this).prev('.amount').val(initValue);
            }

        },
        slide: function(e, ui) {

            // Update display to current value
            $(this).prev('.amount').val(ui.value);

            var current = ($(this).index() / 2) >> 0;
            var total = 0;
            var counter = 0

            slidersTied.not(this).each(function() {

                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");                
                counter += 1;
            });

            total += ui.value;

            if (total != MAX){
                proceed = true;
            }

            var missing = MAX - total;
            console.log("missing: " + missing);

            counter = 0;

            if(proceed) {

                //load elements array
                var elements = [];

                slidersTied.each(function() {
                    elements[counter] = $(this);
                    counter += 1;
                });

                var endIndex = counter - 1;
                counter = endIndex + 1;

                while (missing != 0) {

                    console.log("current counter: " + counter);
                    do {
                        if (counter == 0) 
                        {
                            counter = endIndex;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter = counter - 1;
                        }
                    } while(counter == current)

                    console.log("elemento attuale: " + counter);

                    var value = elements[counter].slider("option", "value");
                    var result = value + missing;

                    if (result >= 0) 
                    {
                        elements[counter].slider('value', result);
                        elements[counter].prev('.amount').val(result);

                        missing = 0;    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        missing = result;
                        elements[counter].slider('value', 0);
                        elements[counter].prev('.amount').val(0);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuQz5/11/

Take care of setting the value of MAX variable to desired value (the sum of all slider's value together...